# POJO optimization

Tags: java, pojo

I was working on an application and observed, we have a number of POJO classes. Each POJO classes have a bunch of getters and setters. Was just thinking do we have an interface which interprets all the attributes and I can do away with all explicitly adding all the getters and setters.

If someone wants they can always override and have their custom implementation.

Comment: Lombok `@Data` / `@Value`.

Comment: can you please share some example

Comment: Go through this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-to-project-lombok-in-java-and-how-to-get-started/

Comment: My Eclipse IDE generates getter/setter classes fairly easily.  I guess most IDEs do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) is your friend!

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Data {
    private int a;
    private int b;
}
```